# About in-app purchase

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, in-app-purchase

Can i use two type of in app purchase in one project ?

Consumables
Non-Consumables
Subscriptions
(chose two type to use)

Thanks in advance..

Comment: What environment are you interested in?  iOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. The In-App Purchases are differentiated by ID, so you can definitely use multiple types in the same project.

Comment: @小穎 陳 If you liked this answer you should tick it (√).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, When you are adding your products in itunesconnect just choose **different product type** . For Example- for product "A"- choose Consumables and for product "B" choose Non - Consumables